# Drupal - Newbie - Need some help in finding content

Tags: drupal

It seems a very simple job but really been tough to perform.

All i need is to edit a content but i cannot find it inside the cms which says "Commerce Kickstart"

The page address of the content is like this:
https://website.com/abc/def-ghi

When i select Content>Manage Content from the top header bar (after logging in as admin the top bar appears) then it shows lots of pages to edit but i couldn't find that particular text inside any of them.

So i decided to download the mysql db and search for the text using notepad++ but i found several instances and i guess its all from some cache table.

I put so many hours on finding this easiest task but failed.

Any advices?

Thanks!

Comment: btw, in some pages i can see VIEW/EDIT/DEVEL button but in some in some i couldn't find such options. Specially the one that i have to change content to. Is this have to do something with permissions? I am logged in from admin account.

Answer (score 0):

Do the pages have content within them?

When you are on the Content Overview page just click on  edit and see if there is anything in them.

From what I can infer you are using Commerce Kickstart and this probably implies that you might need to edit the product instead. Just answering from the top of my head.